# sound stops after scene reloads in unity3d

Tags: unity, music

I'm recently facing problem regarding the inclusion of sounds in my game. Although i have used the technique of DontDestroyOnLoad() for background sounds and that work perfectly fine. But for the casual sound, it is creating problem that it stops during scene reloads. I have my script below that contains AudioClips and AudioSources and that script is attached to an empty game object, and calling that script in different scripts for the playback of the sounds.

**AudioScript.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AudioScript : MonoBehaviour {



    public AudioClip pinshit;

    public AudioClip rowlingball;

    public AudioSource rowling;

    public AudioSource hit;

    public AudioClip cheer;

    public AudioClip strike;

    public Text counttext;

    public AudioClip spare;

    public AudioClip sorrow;

    public AudioClip winaudio;

    GameObject[] music;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        rowling = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        music = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("class");

        if (music.Length == 1)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < music.Length; i++)
            {
                Destroy(music[i]);
            }
        }



    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

To play sound on different actions routines

```
sorrow.clip = GameObject.FindWithTag("class").GetComponent<AudioScript>().sorrow;

                sorrow.Play();

                sorrow.volume = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Was just making a small mistake. I was not calling the audiosource rowling used in AudioScript in another script. Anyhow the correct format is below

```
   GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("class").GetComponent<AudioScript>().rowling.clip = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("class").GetComponent<AudioScript>().sorrow;

   GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("class").GetComponent<AudioScript>().rowling.Play();
```

And that's it!